# Error 9 VBA - Subscript out of Range appears every other run

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

The code below, located in my access database, runs fine half of the time. The other half it gives me: "error 9 subscript out of range," and it highlights the "Set WKS = Workbooks(..." line as the problem. I know that the problem is with it being unsure which workbook it is referencing. However I don't know what to do to make it clearer.

```
Sub fixborderss()
Dim WKS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long


Set WKS = Workbooks("L3 PSR.xls").Worksheets("L-3 Project Status Report")

lastrow = Range("I" & WKS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

WKS.Range("A8:V" & lastrow).Borders(xlEdgeTop).Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
WKS.Range("A8:V" & lastrow).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
WKS.Range("A8:V" & lastrow).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

End Sub
```

Comment: is workbook `L3 PSR.xls` open when this is run?

Comment: Yes, it is opened in a previous macro

Comment: I'm guessing somewhere you have an object variable which references the active `Excel.Application` instance which has the workbook opened.  Qualify `Workbooks` with that object variable ... `Set WKS = objExcel.Workbooks(`

Comment: Later, if you encounter a similar problem at `lastrow = Range(`, change that to `lastrow = WKS.Range(`

Comment: also good practice to qualify the first `Range` in the `lastrow = ` line... `lastrow = WKS.Range("I" & WKS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Ok - that makes sense HansUp. Here's my followup question: In the previous module, I assigned the excel.application instance like this: `set XL = new Excel.Application.` So how the heck do I call that excel instance? I can't just say `set XL = new Excel.Application` again as that will create a new application.

Comment: Aha!  I wondered how you were sharing that object variable! In the current procedure, I guess you could use `GetObject()` to latch on to the Excel application.  Check the help topic for details.

Comment: Hey HansUp - much thanks! Problem solved - it runs correctly 100% of the time. I used `Set XL = GetObject("C:\Users\****\Desktop\L3 PSR.xls").Application` to find the instance in question, and threw that in the front of the WKS variable assignment. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options depending on how your code is constructed:

1) Make `XL` a public variable:

```
Public XL As Excel.Application '// Declare at top of module, outside of any subs/functions
```

2) Pass Excel to the other sub:

```
Set XL = New Excel.Application
'// ... more code

My_Other_Sub XL '// Call sub and pass Excel object

'// Some more code

End Sub

Public Sub My_Other_Sub(ByRef XL As Excel.Application)
    Set ws = XL.Workbooks(1).Sheets(1)
    '// Other code
End Sub
```

3) Use the `GetObject()` method if Excel is already open.

```
Set XL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

If Not XL Is Nothing Then
    Set ws = XL.Workbooks(1).Sheets(1)
End If
```